# FromUri query string web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I'm trying to query data from my database with Web Api. The problem is that I get an error when I send a get request with Postman. I have set breakpoints in my program but the method isn't receiving the request.

```
{
    "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

I try to query the follow string:

```
https://localhost:44384/api/advertentie/search?location=Makarska&property=null&price=null&rooms=null&beds=null&baths=null
```

```
public class QueryModel
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? Rooms { get; set; }
    public int? Beds { get; set; }
    public int? Baths { get; set; }

}
```

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/advertentie/search{Location}/{Property}/{Price}/{Rooms}/{Beds}/{Baths}")]
public IHttpActionResult Search([FromUri] QueryModel query)
{

}
```

Comment: Your route doesn't match your URL. Your URL is using query string, but your route is using slashes. You need to pick one approach or the other.

Comment: I want my query string approach. Do I need to remove the slashes from my route?

Comment: Probably need to remove everything after `search` from your route, as your query string info shouldn't be in your route.

Comment: Hmm, right. Thank you.

Comment: @mason, but what I don't understand is: I have ```ModelState.IsValid``` in ```Search```, but it's returning false. When I look at the error it says ```The value 'null' is not valid for Rooms."``` This implies to all the int's, but I made it a nullable type with the ```?```. When I enter null for ```Location``` and ```Property```, it doesn't give any errors. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mason pointed out, you are using two different URL schemes. If you want to use query parameters, you should use `[FromQuery]`. You would then change your route to simply `[Route("api/advertentie/search")]`. End result would look like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/advertentie/search")]
public IHttpActionResult Search([FromQuery] QueryModel query)
{

}
```